# SQL WHERE NOT EXISTS (skip duplicates)

Tags: sql-server

Hello I'm struggling to get the query below right. What I want is to return rows with unique names and surnames. What I get is all rows with duplicates

This is my sql

```
DECLARE @tmp AS TABLE (Name VARCHAR(100), Surname VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tmp

SELECT CustomerName,CustomerSurname FROM Customers
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT Name,Surname 
 FROM @tmp 
 WHERE Name=CustomerName 
 AND ID Surname=CustomerSurname
GROUP BY Name,Surname )
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction here. 
//Desperate (I tried without GROUP BY as well but get same result)

Comment: Please supply table definition for `Customers` and example data and desired results.

Comment: SQL processes *sets*, and the results for each outermost query are produced "as if" all of the processing occurred in parallel. As such, for your script above, `@tmp` will always be empty while your `INSERT` is being processed. Can you try and explain what you *thought* this query would do?

Comment: What I was hoping to do was to get one 'Steven Smith' rather than every Steven Smith in Customers but also every 'Steven' with a surname which is not 'Smith'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DISTINCT` would do the trick.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName, CustomerSurname
FROM Customers
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efb268/1/0)

If you only want the records that really don't have duplicates (as opposed to getting duplicates represented as a single record) you could use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT CustomerName, CustomerSurname
FROM Customers
GROUP BY CustomerName, CustomerSurname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efb268/3/0)

Comment: I think that isn't what they are asking. This brings back all `CustomerName, CustomerSurname` and the `DISTINCT` makes non unique ones unique. I think they just want the ones that are actually unique.

Comment: @MartinSmith: It seems from the posted code that OP tries to insert only the items that aren't already in the temp table, which, if they got it to work, would be equivalent of distinct, so I'm guessing this is it.

Comment: If there are duplicates in Customers is not relevant for the results I just want one row with each occurrence of the combination Name+Surname. So Martin Smith was correct with the first comment

Comment: @Constanta - I think David's correct, and `DISTINCT` is what you want, from the descriptions you've given. He has been kind enough to add demos too.

Comment: @Constanta: then you should go with my first piece of code, using `DISTINCT`. See the demos. The customer named "A B" is duplicated. In the first demo it is returned once, in the second, it is not returned at all, as per Martin's suggestion.

Comment: Yes David's example worked indeed. Many thanks for taking the time to create the demo as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing that while your @Tmp table is still empty?
If so: your entire "select" is fully evaluated before the "insert" statement, it doesn't do "run the query and add one row, insert the row, run the query and get another row, insert the row, etc."

If you want to insert unique Customers only, use that same "Customer" table in your not exists clause

```
SELECT c.CustomerName,c.CustomerSurname FROM Customers c
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1
 FROM Customers c1
 WHERE c.CustomerName = c1.CustomerName 
 AND c.CustomerSurname = c1.CustomerSurname
 AND c.Id <> c1.Id)
```

If you want to insert a unique set of customers, use "distinct"

Comment: yep empty table. ok I understand 'why' what I tried does not work now thanks beder

Comment: @beder: The query you provided is guaranteed to return 0 rows. Except if there are Nulls in the 2 columns. It's actually equivalent to `SELECT CustomerName, CustomerSurname FROM Customers c
WHERE CustomerName IS NULL OR CustomerSurname IS NULL;`

Comment: If you add `AND c.ID <> c1.ID` in the subquery, it would work as you describe.

Comment: @ypercube indeed, that was a mess up; the correct solution is to use "group by ... having count(1) = 1"

Comment: `GROUP BY` is never the correct solution when there is an `EXISTS` one. (Kidding but still your attempt needs only a minor correction).

Comment: It's a fair point, EXISTS is meant for filterting, GROUP BY is not meant for that. Could be worst though, at least IN was not suggested :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, I thought that @David answer is what you want. But rereading your comments, perhaps you want all combinations of Names and Surnames:

```
SELECT n.CustomerName, s.CustomerSurname
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT CustomerName
      FROM Customers
    ) AS n
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT CustomerSurname
      FROM Customers
    ) AS s ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you're doing a WHERE NOT EXISTS or WHERE EXISTS, or WHERE NOT IN subquery,
you should use what is called a "correlated subquery", as in ypercube's answer above, where table aliases are used for both inside and outside tables (where inside table is joined to outside table).  ypercube gave a good example.

And often, NOT EXISTS is preferred over NOT IN (unless the WHERE NOT IN is selecting from a totally unrelated table that you can't join on.)

Sometimes if you're tempted to do a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  from a small table with no duplicate values in column), you could also do the same thing by joining the main query with that table on the column you want in the EXISTS.  Not always the best or safest solution, might make query slower if there are many rows in that table and could cause many duplicate rows if there are dup values for that column in the joined table -- in which case you'd have to add DISTINCT to the main query, which causes it to SORT the data on all columns.
-- Not efficient at all.

And, similarly, the WHERE NOT IN or NOT EXISTS correlated subqueries can be accomplished (and give the exact same execution plan) if you LEFT OUTER JOIN the table you were going to subquery -- and add a WHERE . IS NULL.
You have to be careful using that, but you don't need a DISTINCT.  Frankly, I prefer to use the WHERE NOT IN subqueries or NOT EXISTS correlated subqueries, because the syntax makes the intention clear and it's hard to go wrong.

And you do not need a DISTINCT in the SELECT inside such subqueries (correlated or not).  It would be a waste of processing (and for WHERE EXISTS or WHERE IN subqueries, the SQL optimizer would ignore it anyway and just use the first value that matched for each row in the outer query).  (Hope that makes sense.)